# Query regarding placeholder in SELECT statement in sqlit3 library

Tags: python, better-sqlite3

I created a table and added records to it but I want to print each record as I add more records.But the code below doesn't seem to be working for me..
Btw I input model from user..

```
Cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Top_Cars WHERE MODEL=?;",(model))
print(Cursor.fetchone())
```

Comment: What is the type of `model`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen string

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen model=input("Input model : ")

Comment: *Does not work* just means nothing. What happens exactly? An error (please show the exact message) of just `fetchone` returning `None`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta It says this :sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a common mistake with tuples. `(model,)` is a 1-tuple, but `(model)` is just a parenthesed expression containing only `model`. As a string is an iterable of characters, `execute` sees as many bindings as letters in `model` word. Fix it trivial:

```
Cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Top_Cars WHERE MODEL=?;",(model,))
```

or:

```
Cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Top_Cars WHERE MODEL=?;",[model])
```

Comment: BTW: I did not see that immediately in you question, but it became evident after you gave the error message. The reason why you should **always** show the exact error messages.

Comment: you are right , this completely got off of my mind...Thanks a bunch.